# call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available

Tags: java, android

I get an error on `CALL_PHONE`
If I remove that condition error of call permission is out
I also add permissions in manifest but android studio highlight the `CALL_back` and if I remove the condition of if then it gives an error

```
  private Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_imp_no);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCall);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9990884476"));

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(imp_no.this, Manifest.permission.**CALL_PHONE**) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        });
   }
  }
```

Comment: you need to add the run time permission and also add it to your manifest. where you are handling the response of permission request ?

Comment: how to add runtime permission I already add  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" /> this but it get error

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Answer (score 0):

you can also use dexter permission library for easy permission check